# Android Studio should start with specific app project

Tags: android-studio, onstart

Android Studio opens always with the last used Projekt.
Is there a way to enter some parameter in the start link ( i will have mor elinks then) so the Android Studio will start with an APp Project i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution for this specific Issue, but a nice workaround.[Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> uncheck Reopen last project on startup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9SjZ.png)